# Put a letter to the front of a string in python

Tags: python, string

is there a quick way to place a `string` in the front of another `string` in python? if so how?

as an example let's say that `string = 'pple'`. How would I put the `string_2 = 'a'` at the start of `string`?

Comment: Note that there is no "char" type in Python.  It's all strings.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about.  Your question was perfectly fine.  It's just important to understand the distinction.  `'a'` could be thought of as a `string` that represents a single character.

Comment: Since strings are immutable there is no tricky way to do this. Just use addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

concatenate it:

`string=char+string`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> strg = 'pple'
>>> char = 'a'
>>> char + strg
'apple'
>>> strg = char + strg
>>> strg
'apple'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example:
    string='a'+string

Answer (score 0):

Lots of correct answers.  You could also use *"string interpolation"* (or just *"string formatting"*, when referring to `str.format`) if you are really looking to do some string manipulating (I only mention it because figuring out what the `%` is called can be frustrating):

```
>>> one_string = 'One string'
>>> two_string = 'two string'
>>> one_two = '%s, %s, red string, blue string' % (one_string, two_string)
>>> one_two
'One string, two string, red string, blue string'
```

I'll leave you to check it out if you like.  See, for example, http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: On modern Pythons the `'{}, {}, ...'.format(one_string, two_string)` [format string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) syntax is preferred. I also generally see people call it _string formatting_ not interpolation. Also possible but overkill for the trivial case: `''.join(char, string)`

Comment: Good point about terminology.  Do you have a link talking about why one should prefer format string syntax?  Seems reasonable, as it subsumes interpolation I guess.

Comment: @Zach: The new formatting system is more powerful in that it allows you to define custom format specifiers in your objects. E.g. if you call `'{:foo}'.format(Foo())`, then the method `Foo.__format__` will get called with `'foo'` as the parameter. For one-off usecases like these either variant is fine though.